# Python crashes when importing classes and modules into tkinter program

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I'm running Python 3.8 in PyCharm IDE, macOs Catalina 10.15.4. While developing my Tkinter program the problem is that if I import any module or some class from another file Python launcher will crash and throw an error:

```
2020-04-22 02:10:57.952 Python[17930:1345160] -[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feb9f73e880
2020-04-22 02:10:57.955 Python[17930:1345160] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feb9f73e880'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff36309d07 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6f02d5bf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff36388c97 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3626e57b ___forwarding___ + 1427
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3626df58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010d65c1f2 TkpInit + 408
    6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010d5cbaac Initialize + 2454
    7   _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x000000010d41f714 Tcl_AppInit + 84
    8   _tkinter.cpython-38-darwin.so       0x000000010d41f032 _tkinter_create + 1362
    9   Python                              0x000000010ce100bf cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 175
    10  Python                              0x000000010cea1e7c call_function + 444
    11  Python                              0x000000010ce9ec8d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25677
    12  Python                              0x000000010cea2cc4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    13  Python                              0x000000010cdd426e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    14  Python                              0x000000010cdd35d7 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    15  Python                              0x000000010cdd4bdf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    16  Python                              0x000000010ce2ad41 slot_tp_init + 145
    17  Python                              0x000000010ce26219 type_call + 297
    18  Python                              0x000000010cdd3785 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    19  Python                              0x000000010cea1ed5 call_function + 533
    20  Python                              0x000000010ce9ed1a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25818
    21  Python                              0x000000010cea2cc4 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    22  Python                              0x000000010ce98764 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    23  Python                              0x000000010cee8370 PyRun_FileExFlags + 336
    24  Python                              0x000000010cee7a60 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 864
    25  Python                              0x000000010cf04cdf Py_RunMain + 2159
    26  Python                              0x000000010cf0501f pymain_main + 223
    27  Python                              0x000000010cf0521b Py_BytesMain + 43
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff701d4cc9 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don't know what's causing this but it is stopping me from developing my program so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: I had similar issues on a Mac with Python3.8 and Tkinter. I solved it by downgrading to Python3.7.

Comment: @NoahBroyles just tried that and it didn't help, but thank you anyway